# phabricator curl commandline for creating repository

Tags: bitnami, phabricator

Can somebody help me please to create a git Repository with curl ?

I try based on documentation:

```
curl  https://my-url.eu/api/diffusion.repository.edit \
    -d api.token=api-my-token \
    -d transactions[0][type]=vcs \
    -d transactions[0][value]=git \
    -d transactions[1][type]=name \
    -d transactions[1][value]=testing-api-repo \
    -d objectIdentifier=
```

Return:
zsh: no matches found: transactions[0][type]=vcs

Also my second question: is there a way to create conduit-api-token via cli ?? it would be very useful for automation

Answer (score 0):

I found it :

```
curl -k -s -X POST https://URL/api/diffusion.repository.edit \
-d api.token=api-TOKEN_HERE \
-d 'transactions[0][type]=vcs' \
-d 'transactions[0][value]=git' \
-d 'transactions[1][type]=name' \
-d 'transactions[1][value]=testing' | jq -r
```